# Input in React webpage not displaying

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am following Coding with kevins SQL, Node, Express, and React JS tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rK6oTTbVbcY

I am at the point in the tutorial where I am supposed to input data into the webpage textbox, and upon clicking submit the data will display on the bottom of the webpage

Whenever I try to enter the first and last name in the corresponding textbox, it doesn't display at the bottom of the page

here is my code from my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
```

import React, {useState} from 'react';

```
function App() {
       const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({EmployeeID: 0,  Firstname: '', Lastname: '', Age: 0, Gender: ''});
  const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState([]);
  const setInput = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    console.log(value);
  
    if (name === 'EmployeeID' || name === 'Age') {
      setEmployee(prevState => ({...prevState,
        [name]: parseInt(name)
      }) );
      return;
    }
  
    setEmployee(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  }
  const fetchData = async () => {
   
    console.log(employee);
    
    const newData = await fetch('/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: employee.Firstname
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    console.log(newData[0]); 
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        type="number" 
        name="EmployeeID" 
        placeholder="EmployeeID"
        onChange={setInput}>
      </input>
      <input 
        name="Firstname" 
        placeholder="Firstname" 
        onChange={setInput}>
      </input>
      <input 
          name="Lastname" 
          placeholder="Lastname" 
          onChange={setInput}>
      </input>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        name="Age" 
        placeholder="Age"
        onChange={setInput}>
      </input>
      <input 
          name="Gender" 
          placeholder="Gender" 
          onChange={setInput}>
      </input>
      <button onClick={()=> fetchData()}>Clicky</button>
      <button onClick={()=> fetchData()}>Create</button>
      <p>EmployeeID: {returnedData.EmployeeID}</p>
      <p>Firstname: {returnedData.Firstname}</p>
      <p>Lastname: {returnedData.Lastname}</p>
      <p>Age: {returnedData.Age}</p>
      <p>Gender: {returnedData.Gender}</p>
      {returnedData}
      {returnedData.name}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`enter code here`
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And does the problem really have anything to do with SQL Server? Seems more likely a code issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom of the page you try to display the content of `returnedData` , whereas `setReturnedData` is never called inside the code. you are just calling `setInput` to change `employee`.

`returnedData` is still an empty array `[]`.

I believe you want to call the `setReturnedData` inside `fetchData` to update based on your API Call. Do this and it will probably display the data :)

Little hint for StackOverflow: instead of sharing screenshots, consider using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for creating an editable Project with your code, which might be easier to read and provide a solution for you.

Comment: What is the proper syntax to call setReturnedData? I am new to react so I am just unsure how to implement it in my code

Comment: setReturnedData is a function to set the state of returnedData, can be called like this for example in your fetchData function : `setReturnedData(res.json())`

Comment: [Here is a good tutorial on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6P86uwfdR0)

Comment: So, once I put setReturnedData() inside fetchData, what is the syntax I put inside a setReturnedData() function in order to display the key value pair into the front end page? I am able to pull from the database and display the result on the console line. Some of the previous ones I've tried are setReturnedData(newData.result) and setReturnedData(newData[0])

Comment: this depends on the content of your newData, how does the result of newData look like ?  console.log(newData) , the content of returnedData should be something like {EmployeeID: 0,  Firstname: '', Lastname: '', Age: 0, Gender: ''} , in order to be shown properly in the frontend. So look where you find this type of Object in your newData fetch result.